# MVVM Light navigation service - parameters in windows rt

Tags: mvvm, navigation, winrt-xaml

I see in the MVVM Light toolkit there is a NavigationService. This is very straightforward when you are just navigating to a view and passing no data i.e.

```
_navigationService.Navigate(typeof(DetailView));
```

There is an overload on the Navigate method which takes an object parameter i.e.

```
_navigationService.Navigate(typeof(DetailView), this.SelectedItem.Id);
```

Question is, how do I then retrieve the parameter in my target view model?

Comment: The `OnNavigatedTo` override in your page receives the `NavigationParameter`. You can pass said parameter from your View to your ViewModel. Conversely, you can send a Message to the ViewModel using the `Messenger` service that Mvvm also provides to send it separately from navigation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up with the following

```
public interface IView
{
    IViewModel ViewModel { get; }
}

public interface IViewModel
{
    void Initialise(object parameter);
}
```

Then in my view's code behind;

```
public sealed partial class MyView : IView
{
    public ViewModel.IViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return this.DataContext as IViewModel; }
    }

    public MyView()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {            
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        if (e.Parameter != null)
        {
            this.ViewModel.Initialise(e.Parameter);
        }
    }        
}
```

From there I can now use the parameter in my ViewModel where I am implementing the IViewModel interface.

```
public void Initialise(object parameter)
{
   if (parameter != null)
   {
       // do something 
   }
}
```

Comment: how and where is OnNavigatedTo defined so that you are able to override it in `MyView`?

Comment: This is defined in the page out of the box - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227508